# How to list file starting with and ending with particular pattern in linux

Tags: linux, shell

Need help to list a file having some pattern like below:

```
Sep 19 00:02 gc-2019-08-18_07-23-09.log.1.current.zip
Sep 19 00:02 gc-2019-08-21_07-58-10.log.3.current
Sep 19 00:02 gc_2019-08-25_07-58-11.log.5.current
Sep 19 01:41 gc_2019-09-18_17-40-28.log.0.current
```

I want to get the file starting with gc and ending with .current only.

The thing is I don't want to go with `"ls -ltr gc*"` because I have some other files starting with gc which I don't want to print?

Can someone please advise for this?

Comment: `ls -l gc*current` should do it.

Comment: @iamauser OP wants files ending with .current , but this command will give you file ending with current and .current as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` as mentioned by Tim Biegeleisen

But if you want to stick to `ls` then you can give a try to below commands as well.

1. `ls -l gc*.current`
2. `ls -1|grep "^gc.*\.current$"`
3. `ls -1| grep "^gc"| grep "\.current$"`

`^`: Fetch all files which will start with `gc`

`$`: Fetch all the files ending with `.current`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `find` with a glob pattern:

```
find . -name 'gc*.current'
```